# Unable to start Apache2 service on Solaris 10

Tags: apache-2.2, debugging, solaris-10

This is a default installation of Solaris 10 x86. No tweaks or customization.

1) I first enable apache2.

**bash-3.00# svcadm enable apache2**

2) Restart apache2

**bash-3.00# svcadm restart apache2**

3) Check whether the service is running.

**bash-3.00# svcs | grep apache**

```
legacy_run     Aug_08   lrc:/etc/rc3_d/S50apache

maintenance    18:41:16 svc:/network/http:apache2
```

4) The service has gone into maintenance and hence I am looking at the explanation of what is wrong.

**bash-3.00# svcs -xv**

```
svc:/network/http:apache2 (Apache 2 HTTP server)


    State: maintenance since Thu Aug 11 18:41:16 2011

    Reason: Start method exited with $SMF_EXIT_ERR_CONFIG.

    See: http://sun.com/msg/SMF-8000-KS

    See: man -M /usr/apache2/man -s 8 httpd

    See: /var/svc/log/network-http:apache2.log
```

5) Cat the log file.

**bash-3.00# cat /var/svc/log/network-http:apache2.log**

```
[ Aug  4 15:09:31 Rereading configuration. ]

[ Aug 11 12:54:23 Enabled. ]

[ Aug 11 12:59:58 Executing start method ("/lib/svc/method/http-apache2 start") ]

[ Aug 11 12:59:58 Method "start" exited with status 96 ]

[ Aug 11 17:35:48 Leaving maintenance because disable requested. ]

[ Aug 11 17:35:48 Disabled. ]

[ Aug 11 17:40:26 Enabled. ]

[ Aug 11 17:40:26 Executing start method ("/lib/svc/method/http-apache2 start") ]

[ Aug 11 17:40:26 Method "start" exited with status 96 ]

[ Aug 11 17:41:05 Leaving maintenance because clear requested. ]

[ Aug 11 17:41:05 Enabled. ]

[ Aug 11 17:41:05 Executing start method ("/lib/svc/method/http-apache2 start") ]

[ Aug 11 17:41:05 Method "start" exited with status 96 ]

[ Aug 11 18:40:30 Leaving maintenance because clear requested. ]

[ Aug 11 18:40:30 Enabled. ]

[ Aug 11 18:40:30 Executing start method ("/lib/svc/method/http-apache2 start") ]

[ Aug 11 18:40:30 Method "start" exited with status 96 ]

[ Aug 11 18:41:16 Leaving maintenance because clear requested. ]

[ Aug 11 18:41:16 Enabled. ]

[ Aug 11 18:41:16 Executing start method ("/lib/svc/method/http-apache2 start") ]

[ Aug 11 18:41:16 Method "start" exited with status 96 ]
```

---

I don't know how I can proceed from this place "Method "start" exited with status 96"

Comment: what does tail /var/apache2/2.2/logs/error_log says?

Comment: @Troydm: at the point that `SMF_EXIT_ERR_CONFIG` (96) is generated SMF hasn't attempted to start apache. Have a look at `/lib/svc/method/http-apache2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SMF_EXIT_ERR_CONFIG` code is returned when the SMF checks for the existence of the `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file and it is missing. A default Solaris Apache install will be provided with several template files in `/etc/apache2`, copy one of these to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` e.g.

```
cp /etc/apache2/httpd.std.conf /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Once you have a `httpd.conf` file, any subsequent error messages will be sent to `/var/apache2/logs/error_log`.

You may need to make changes to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to get Apache running in your environment.

Comment: Doing a cp /etc/apache2/httpd-std.conf /etc/apache2/httpd.conf got it working! Many thanks Lain! But surprisingly, some other boxes where apache works without any issues doesnt have a httpd.conf file, they just have the default http-std.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

try to:
svcadm -v enable /network/http:apache2

http://www.mattzone.com/sol10_apache.html

Regards!